# Convert ODBC SQL query to use prepared statements

Tags: php, odbc, prepared-statement

I'm using ODBC (Win32) to connect to our Pervasive SQL database. I have post variables that I need to insert into SQL queries and later extract individual rows.

Here's an example of what I have so far but isn't working for some reason:

`$sql_bin2=odbc_prepare($conn,'SELECT TOP 1 icitemo.value FROM icitemo WHERE icitemo.itemno = ? AND icitemo.optfield = ?');`

`$result_bin2=odbc_execute($sql_bin2, array($barcode, $var_bin2));`

`while (odbc_fetch_row($result_bin2))
{
    $bin2=odbc_result($result_bin2,"VALUE");
}`

Nothing gets returned. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith I just posted the answer to this. When I made this post I was restricted from answering my own question and I forgot to come back to answer at a later date. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer to this:

```
$sql_bin2 = odbc_prepare($conn, 'SELECT TOP 1 icitemo.value FROM icitemo WHERE icitemo.itemno = ? AND icitemo.optfield = ?');

odbc_execute($sql_bin2, array($barcode, $var_bin2));

if ($sql_bin2) {
    $bin2 = odbc_result($sql_bin2,"VALUE"); }
```