# Login page not preventing invalid usernames

Tags: php, sql-server, session, input

I have a form with only a username that will allow for access to two pages depending an users authority level in an MS SQL database.

If their authority level is 10 then they will log into the 'normal' page, however anything more and they will be logged into an admin page with more functionality. This all works fine, however It's letting anything typed into the username to log in.

I'm struggling to prevent it logging in any username that isn't in the database. This is what I have so far...

```
$conn = odbc_connect(database connection stuff here);
$login = $_POST['login'];
$sqlquery = "SELECT u.authorityLevel, u.employeeNo, e.knownAs FROM common.dbo.users as u JOIN 
common.dbo.employees AS e on e.employeeNo = u.employeeNo WHERE u.employeeNo = '".$login."'";
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sqlquery);
$user = odbc_fetch_array($result);
$userExists = odbc_num_rows($sqlquery);

if((isset($_SESSION['login']['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['login'] 
['logged_in'])==true){

if(isset($_POST)){
  if ((int)$user['authorityLevel'] > 10) {
    header("location: indexAdmin.php");
    $row = $user;
    $_SESSION['sessionUserName'] = $row['knownAs'];
} elseif ((int)$user['authorityLevel'] = 10) {
    header("location: confirmedJobs.php");
    $row = $user;
    $_SESSION['sessionUserName'] = $row['knownAs'];
} else ((int)$user['authorityLevel'] < 10){
    header("location: loginPage.php");
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: You didn't check if a record exists, `$userExists = odbc_num_rows($sqlquery);` you're just declaring the variable for it.

Comment: Why is there a login page if the only "security" feature is assuming no one can find out the name of an authority level > 10 account? Actually, it's enough looking over an admin's shoulder at the right moment to get full access.
In addition to that, please read up on how to use "prepared statements in ODBC". Otherwise, a user named `lulz'; DROP TABLE common.dbo.users; --` might come by at some point.

Comment: That code is open to SQL injection - please check how to handle `$login` properly in your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only declaring this variable:

```
$userExists = odbc_num_rows($sqlquery);
```

but not using it.

This is the syntax to check if a record exists:

```
 if($userExists >0) {...}
```

**Edit:** (I overlooked something).

This line is using the wrong variable for it:

```
$userExists = odbc_num_rows($sqlquery);
```

In conjunction with:

```
$result = odbc_exec($conn, $sqlquery);
```

Therefore it should read as:

```
$userExists = odbc_num_rows($result);
```

`odbc_num_rows()` is used against the executed query, not the raw query.

You are also open to an SQL injection, use a prepared statement:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-prepare.php
- [Convert ODBC SQL query to use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9603865/convert-odbc-sql-query-to-use-prepared-statements)

Comment: I added '$userExists >0' next to the ISSET($_POST) but it won't accept any username now

Comment: @mat1986 You need to add the `if($userExists >0) {...}` under `$userExists = odbc_num_rows($sqlquery);`. The `{...}` is the code you want to execute inside that conditional statement. If something else is failing you, then you would have to check for errors via php's error reporting or the query itself.

Comment: Gave it a try but the issue remains the same, won't accept any username. Checked the console and error log and nothing came back. Thank you for you time though, I'll keep trying.

Comment: @mat1986 Welcome. I overlooked something. Please reload my answer and look under **Edit:**. You used the wrong variable.

Comment: Ah you got it. Knew it was something inconspicuous. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

anything you fill in will make isset($_POST) return true.
Once you're in that if-then block, any choice leads to a page.

How about :

```
if(isset($_POST) && $userExists)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Gave it a try but it's not giving access to any username now, even one I've confirmed exists in the database